# The meaning of " He took most of those long drives with his daughter — all through the Southeast and as far away as Dallas."

Tags: meaning, grammar, comparative-constructions

So, a person lives in North Carolina and he usually takes his daughter across the states with his car. And the following sentence,

> He took most of those long drives with his daughter — all through the Southeast and as far away as Dallas.

Did he actually take the daughter to Dallas or the total distance of those long drives is as large as the distance from his house to Dallas?

Comment: **as far away as Dallas** does not mean "the sum total of their trips equalled the distance from their home to Dallas". Rather it means that their longest trip was to Dallas. And I think you knew that but rejected the clear meaning because you think that distance is too far to drive. So this is a cultural question more than a language question. In the US, it is not uncommon for people to drive coast to coast, 3000 miles stopping along the way overnight. A 1000-mile trip from NC to TX would take ~16 hours on the highway so it would take two days driving with a stopover at a motel along the way.

Comment: Thanks for the specific answer. Yes, I thought it was strange. Since the last paragraph described her father had his job in North Carolina and was not a sports parent. So, I thought he was not willing to take her to the soccer game really far away. Anyway, thank you for giving me not only grammatical but also very well explained cultural background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He and his daughter went to Dallas.  The sentence doesn't describe the length of the drives.  It describes the locations of the drives.  We deduce the lengths from the starting point and the locations (the Southeast and Dallas).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I interpreted that the total distance of round trip from his home to his daughter's sports game held in the Southeast was the total distance from his home to Dallas. I thought it cost a lot and unusual to drive such a long distance from North Carolina to Dallas by car. Anyway, thanks for answering!

Comment: Cheers, @kimi.  You are correct, it would be expensive to drive from North Caroline to Dallas, Texas.  It is definitely a "long drive."

Comment: Yes. The article says such a "long drive" took his daughter to US women's national team of soccer. Thank you.